# JAVA JPA SPRING - IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, jpa

@Query(value = "SELECT i.productNumber FROM Product as i ORDER BY i.productNumber DESC")
public String getLastProductNumber(); // this is my query,

// this is my generator, I'd like to generate add by 1 when I published product everytime,

```
private String setProductNumber() {
    try {
        String value = productRepository.getLastProductNumber();
        System.out.println("Get Last OrderNumber: " + value);

        long currentValue = 0;
        if (!(value == null || value.isEmpty())) {
            currentValue = Long.parseLong(value);
        }

        String result = String.format("%08d", currentValue + 1);

        return result;
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        String result = "00000001";
        return result;
```

but it caused error after get 2 productNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please check this example

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT i.productNumber FROM Product as i ORDER BY i.productNumber 
  DESC") 
  public List<String> getLastProductNumber();
```

Comment: Hi. I'm trying your example, how should I revise SetProductNumber()?

Comment: Using List<String>  value  =  projectRepository.getProductNumber() and using foreach

Comment: Welcome @juststarted